# Migrating from bower + gulp to webpack - injecting dependencies to html

Tags: webpack, gulp, bower

I'm migrating from bower + gulp. I used to use the gulp-inject plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject with this style of injecting individual dependencies:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My index</title>
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <!-- bower installed css files will go here... -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- inject:css -->
  <!-- built css files will go here... -->
  <!-- endinject -->
</head>
<body>

  <!-- bower:js -->
  <!-- bower installed scripts will go here... -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- inject:js -->
  <!-- app scripts will go here... -->
  <!-- endinject -->
</body>
</html>
```

And for production, I would minify all of the dependencies into one js, with a hash of current time-stamp, to override any caching done by the browser.

Now, I'm trying to move to webpack (as part of removing bower, and using npm instead).

I'm wondering about two things, both in the area of html dependency injections:

1. What is the best practice for **dev environment** with webpack. I don't want the other developers to have to deal with one big bundle.js (guessing which file and debugging are harder). However, I don't want to manually keep the individual script src=... tags.
2. For **prod env**, I'm not sure what is the best way to do:
   `<script src="bundle-[timestampHash].js"/>`

Or maybe some best practice with avoid browser cache issues with webpack.

Thank you